# How to pass an empty string as a ConverterPararmeter?

Tags: wpf, binding

Hello I have a Binding that I am using along with a converter, I want the parameter that is transferred to the converter should be an empty string.
Is there a way I can pass it via an inline binding?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can actually use single quotes inline to pass an empty string, like so:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource someConverter}, ConverterParameter=''}" />
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to do it inline, you can use the static String.Empty property.  You need to add a namespace definition for clr-namespace:System to use it.

In your Window definition (or whichever control you're using):

```
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Then you can use something like this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource someConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static System:String.Empty}}" />
```

Comment: Personally I think this is a little better than using the multiline version because people tend to see Converter="" as an unset property (probably one that used to be set and got missed during a refactor) and delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of defining the binding in a single line:

```
<Control Binding={Property, Converter={StaticResource someConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource someParameter}} />
```

You can define it multi-line and specify attributes individually:

```
<Control>
    <Control.Binding>
        <Binding Path="Property" Converter="{StaticResource someConverter}" ConverterParameter="" />
    </Control.Binding>
</Control>
```

Pretty sure that'll do what you're looking for.